# Triggering a shell script on remote machine

Tags: linux, shell, automation

I'm trying a automate a job, which involves, performing certain steps via shell script, do "SCP" of few files to remote machine and trigger a shell script on the remote machine.

Is there a way to achieve this task using shell script or any other scripts?

Thanks in advance,
cherryhitech

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ssh` to run a remote script, e.g.

```
$ scp some_files remote_host:some_directory/
$ ssh remote_host my_script
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a shell script.  Try looking [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) for an introduction.  As Paul R said, use scp to copy files to or from that server.

If by "automate" you mean "schedule to run automatically", check out [cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).  Running the script at midnight every night would mean running `crontab -e` and then adding the following line:

```
0 0 * * * /path_to_script
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to scp files and/or run commands via SSH in a script, make sure to set up SSH authentication using public keys. That way you won't be prompted to login, and the script will be much more 'script-like' (non interactive).

Here's how to do the above:
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Once done, you can scp from a script -

```
scp localfile remotehost:remotepath
```

Similarly you can run things on the remote host -

```
ssh remotehost uname -r
```

or

```
ssh remotehost /path/to/remote/script
```

Comment: Thank! Basically, I was looking for "ssh remotehost /path/to/remote/script"

Answer (score 0):

run `remote-script.sh` on `remote-host`:

```
ssh user@remote-host ". remote-script.sh"
```

with key authentication:

```
ssh -i local/path/to/remote/key user@remote-host ". remote-script.sh"
```